# Do Any Protestant Churches do Stations of the Cross?

Tags: protestantism, comparative-christianity, liturgy, stations-of-the-cross

I was reading [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/88924/what-do-protestants-make-of-the-earliest-marian-prayer) and wondering how Protestants, in general, would react to a Catholic Stations of the Cross service.  I'm not sure of the history of the idea of the Stations of the Cross, although I know there's a handful of extra-bibilical things in it. I can't see it counter to the Bible, but I don't know if Protestants would feel comfortable singing *Stabat Mater*, even though that's not a requirement.

So my question is, are the Stations of the Cross a good ecumenical form of worship, and if so, have they been used independently in Protestant churches and what forms to they take? Are there any parts that differ intentionally from the normal 14 stations found in Latin Rite Catholic Churches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do Any Protestant Churches do Stations of the Cross?**

The short answer is **yes**.

Anglicans are considered by many to be Protestants and they pray the ***(Stations of the Cross***. Every major encyclopedia includes Anglicans as being Protestant.

[St Mary Magdalene’s Anglican Church](https://stmarymagdalenes.weebly.com/the-stations-of-the-cross.html) promotes its usage.

> Protestants can be differentiated according to how they have been influenced by important movements since the Reformation, today regarded as branches. Some of these movements have a common lineage, sometimes directly spawning individual denominations. Due to the earlier stated multitude of denominations, this section discusses only the largest denominational families, or branches, widely considered to be a part of Protestantism. These are, in alphabetical order: Adventist, **Anglican**, Baptist, Calvinist (Reformed), Lutheran, Methodist and Pentecostal. - [Major branches of Protestantism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestantism)

Lutherans also pray the Stations of the Cross. The [First English Evangelical Lutheran Church](https://flcpittsburgh.org/worship/prayer/stations-of-the-cross/) has a website on this devotion.

> Stations of the Cross, also called Way of the Cross, a series of 14 pictures or carvings portraying events in the Passion of Christ, from his condemnation by Pontius Pilate to his entombment. The series of stations is as follows: (1) Jesus is condemned to death, (2) he is made to bear his cross, (3) he falls the first time, (4) he meets his mother, (5) Simon of Cyrene is made to bear the cross, (6) Veronica wipes Jesus’ face, (7) he falls the second time, (8) the women of Jerusalem weep over Jesus, (9) he falls the third time, (10) he is stripped of his garments, (11) he is nailed to the cross, (12) he dies on the cross, (13) he is taken down from the cross, and (14) he is placed in the sepulchre. The images are usually mounted on the inside walls of a church or chapel but may also be erected in such places as cemeteries, corridors of hospitals and religious houses, or on mountainsides.
>
> The devotional exercise of visiting and praying in front of each of the 14 stations and meditating on the Passion of Christ stems from the practice of early Christian pilgrims who visited the scenes of the events in Jerusalem and walked the traditional route from the supposed location of Pilate’s house to Calvary. Tradition holds that Mary, the mother of Jesus, set up stone markers at her home outside Jerusalem to prayerfully retrace the steps of her son’s Passion, but the origin of the devotion in its present form is not clear. The number of stations originally observed in Jerusalem was considerably smaller than 14. In the early 16th century, Ways of the Cross were established in Europe, and the tradition of 14 stations probably derived from the best known of them, that at Leuven (1505). The Franciscans long popularized the practice, and in the 18th century they bowed to Western Christian devotional feeling and provided 14 stations in Jerusalem. The traditional stations have been recently supplemented with the Via Lucis (the Way of Light), in which the meditations focus on the resurrected Christ.
>
> Prayerful meditation through the Stations of the Cross is especially common during Lent and on Fridays throughout the year, in commemoration of Christ’s Crucifixion on Good Friday. **The devotion may be done individually or in a group and is particularly important in Roman Catholic, Anglican, and Lutheran traditions**. Each station is commonly visited with some variation of the prayer “We adore you, O Christ, and we bless you. Because by your holy cross you have redeemed the world” and with a reading from a relevant passage of Scripture. Both St. Francis of Assisi and St. Alphonso Maria de’ Liguori wrote devotional guides for the Stations of the Cross that remain popular. - [**Stations of the Cross**](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Stations-of-the-Cross)

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stations_of_the_Cross) adds Methodists to their list.

> The Stations of the Cross or the Way of the Cross, also known as the Way of Sorrows or the Via Crucis, refers to a series of images depicting Jesus Christ on the day of his crucifixion and accompanying prayers. The stations grew out of imitations of the Via Dolorosa in Jerusalem, which is a traditional processional route symbolising the actual path Jesus walked to Mount Calvary. The objective of the stations is to help the Christian faithful to make a spiritual pilgrimage through contemplation of the Passion of Christ. It has become one of the most popular devotions and the stations can be found in many Western Christian churches, including **Anglican, Lutheran, [Methodist](https://web.archive.org/web/20150417235143/http://www.trinityevansville.org/stations-of-the-cross/), and Roman Catholic**.